# Date.parse unexpected return string

Tags: javascript, date

I know there are lots of answers out there on this topic (too many to read all of them), but I am failing to understand why `Date.parse` is returning

```
'Sun Oct 21 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)'
```

from the string `'2018-10-20T23:00:00Z'`

All times return +1hr

Am I missing the obvious? Presumably it is something to do with the `+0100 GMT`, but what do I need to do to make sure that it parses correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Date.parse returns a number, not the string you've posted. Use of Date.parse to parse strings is not recommended (I'd say never use it).

Comment: `Date.parse` does not return a string!?

Comment: It appears your timezone is GMT +1. What are you expecting?

Comment: Oops - sorry, I was confusing it with another issue. What I meant was that the Date function itself is returning the date +1hr. i,e, new Date('2018-10-20T23:00:00Z') gives midnight

Comment: If you have parsed an UTC string to a date object (not a number), you will need to use `.toUTCString()` instead of `.toString()` (which would use your local timezone) for formatting it with UTC again.

Comment: Ah, Obviously I do not understand timezones correctly.  I am in the UK, current time zone therefore is GMT.  October 20th will still be BST, +1hr, but I want to retrieve the local time, just as I enter it in regardless of whether it is GMT or BST.  I am just putting a time for an event into a text box, retrieving it and creating an ical to pass to my calendar.

Comment: If you want the string parsed as "local" (i.e. based on the host system timezone setting), remove the trailing "Z". ISO 8601 format strings without a timezone are treated as local (except for date only forms like 2017-10-20, which is treated by Date.parse as UTC, contrary to ISO 8601). Note also that parsing by the Date constructor and Date.parse are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would strongly recommend that you **never** use the *Date* constructor (or *Date.parse*, they are equivalent for parsing) to parse strings. Always use a small function or suitable library (suggestions with links below).

If parsed per ECMA-262, then '2018-10-20T23:00:00Z' will be parsed as UTC. If you send the resulting date to output using *toString* (or via a method that calls *toString* like `console.log(new Date())`), then generally the host timezone is used to compute "local" values.

The format of the string produced by *toString* is implementation dependent, so may not include the timezone, or might display it in an unexpected manner, and might be different in different hosts.

According to ECMA-262, if you want '2018-10-20T23:00:00Z' to be treated as local, remove the "Z":

```js
var s = '2018-10-20T23:00:00Z';
var t = s.replace(/z$/i,'');
console.log(t);
console.log(new Date(t).toString());
```

However, following on from my first comment, Safari 10.0.3 seems to treat the string as UTC even if the Z is omitted, so your results may be incorrect depending on the host. Firefox seems to get it right.

I can't stress strongly enough that you should not rely on *Date* or *Date.parse* for parsing. Ever.

While writing your own parser for a particular format is easy, some feel much better using a library. Consider [fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) (which is small and does parsing and formatting) or [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) (which is not exactly petite but also helps with arithmetic and can include timezone functionality).

E.g. here is a small ISO extended format parser that tries to be as compatible as possible and use Date methods as little as possible:

```js
/* Parse ISO date string in format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss+hh:mm or Z
** @param (string} s - string to parse in ISO 8601 extended format
**                     yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss+/-hh:mm or z
**                     time zone can omit separator, so +05:30 or +0530
** @returns {Date}   - returns a Date object. If any value out of range,
**                     returns an invalid date.
*/
function parseISO(s) {
  // Create base Date object
  var date = new Date();
  var invalidDate = new Date(NaN);
  // Set some defaults
  var sign = -1, tzMins = 0;
  var tzHr, tzMin;
  // Trim leading and trailing whitespace
  s = s.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'').toUpperCase();
  // Get parts of string and split into numbers
  var d  = (s.match(/^\d+(-\d+){0,2}/)             || [''])[0].split(/\D/);
  var t  = (s.match(/[\sT]\d+(:\d+){0,2}(\.\d+)?/) || [''])[0].split(/\D/);
  var tz = (s.match(/Z|[+\-]\d\d:?\d\d$/)          || [''])[0];

  // Resolve timezone to minutes, may be Z, +hh:mm or +hhmm
  // substr is old school but more compatible than slice
  // Don't need to split into parts but makes validation easier
  if (tz) {
    sign  = /^-/.test(tz)? 1 : -1;
    tzHr  = tz == 'Z'? 0 : tz.substr(1,2);
    tzMin = tz == 'Z'? 0 : tz.substr(tz.length - 2, 2)*1;
    tzMins = sign * (tzHr*60 + tzMin);
  }

  // Validation
  function isLeap(year){return year % 4 != 0 || year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0}
  // Check number of date parts and month is valid
  if (d.length > 3 || d[1] < 1 || d[1] > 12) return invalidDate;
  // Test day is valid
  var monthDays = [,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
  var monthMax = isLeap(d[0]) && d[1] == 2? 29 : monthDays[d[1]];
  if (d[2] < 1 || d[1] > monthMax) return invalidDate;
  // Test time parts
  if (t.length > 5 || t[1] > 23 || t[2] > 59 || t[3] > 59 || t[4] > 999) return invalidDate;
  // Test tz within bounds
  if (tzHr > 12 || tzMin > 59) return invalidDate;

  // If there's a timezone, use UTC methods, otherwise local
  var method = tz? 'UTC' : '';
  
  // Set date values
  date['set' + method + 'FullYear'](d[0], (d[1]? d[1]-1 : 0), d[2]||1);
  // Set time values - first member is '' from separator \s or T
  date['set' + method + 'Hours'](t[1] || 0, (+t[2]||0) + tzMins, t[3]||0, t[4]||0);

  return date;
}

console.log('UTC  : ' + parseISO('2018-10-20T23:00:00Z').toString());
console.log('Local: ' + parseISO('2018-10-20T23:00:00').toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm sure I can sort it now

Answer (score 0):

Date object represents a single moment of time, regardless of time zone.

Think about this, right at this moment, your clock in GMT+1 timezone is showing 15:00.  The other person's clock living in GMT+0 is showing 14:00.
The clock (representation of time) is different, but the moment of time (the value in the Date object) is the same.

This is what you are seeing in the code.  `2018-10-20T23:00:00Z` equals to `2018-10-21T00:00:00 GMT+1`.  By equal I mean they are the exact same moment of time, but just represent in different time zone.